# Java - Calling another method for input within Switch Case

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, case

As I wanted to prevent confusion from my previous post, I am creating a new thread.

I wish to retrieve input after a Case is successful. However, I tried ways to retrieve input after Case 'A' is satisfied but to no avail.

Thank you for any help provided.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    char choice = getInput(sc);
     String result;

    switch (choice) {
        case ('a'): result = "u choose a";
        System.out.println(result);

        //I wish to display result from getInputA method here as well.
        break;
    }
}

private static char getInput(Scanner sc) 
{
System.out.println("Enter a");
char choice = sc.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase().charAt(0); 

while (choice != 'a')
{
    System.out.println("You have entered an invalid entry.");
    System.out.println("Enter a");
    choice = sc.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
}

return choice;

}
    private static String getInputA (String inputA) 
    //***How may I get input from this method in the main method?***
    {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
    String fName=sc.next();
    System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
    String lName=sc.next();

    String output=("Your name is: "+fName+ " " +lName);

    return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to call your method if you want its code to run.

Second, it is best to pass the scanner instead of creating a new one.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        char choice = getInput(sc);
        String result;

        switch (choice) {
            case ('a'): 
                result = "u choose a";
                System.out.println(result);

                //I wish to display result from getInputA method here as well.
                result = getInputA(sc);
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
        }
    }

    private static char getInput(Scanner sc) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a");
        char choice = sc.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase().charAt(0); 

        while (choice != 'a')
        {
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid entry.");
            System.out.println("Enter a");
            choice = sc.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        }
        return choice;
    }
    private static String getInputA(Scanner sc) 
    {
        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
        String fName=sc.next();
        System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
        String lName=sc.next();
        String output=("Your name is: "+fName+ " " +lName);
        return output;
    }
}
```